# SharePoint 2013 : Updating user profile property using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, powershell, user-profile-property

I am working on a powershell script to update the following user profile property on my SharePoint 2013 enviornment,

1. Personal Site
2. Personal Site Capabilities: 0
3. Feed service provider defined identifier

However I see this property as "Get" property in the User Profile class.  We could update this using the Central Admin application.

Any one has done this using PowerShell ?

Any pointers

Comment: Have you found an answer yet? I've been looking into the same issue. I'm not sure why SharePoint doesn't re-map these if the mysite already exists. It seems like a pretty significant oversight to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a handy Powershell script I just used for updating the Personal Capabilities int:

```
#Set up default variables
#My Site URL
$mySiteUrl = "http://spdomain/my/"

#The part of the picture URL you are trying to find
$currentValue = "0"

#The value that will replace the above
$newValue = "14"

#The internal name for Property
$upAttribute = "SPS-PersonalSiteCapabilities"

#Get site objects and connect to User Profile Manager service
$site = Get-SPSite $mySiteUrl

$context = Get-SPServiceContext $site
$profileManager = New-Object   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)

$profiles = $profileManager.GetEnumerator()

foreach ($userProfile in $profiles)
{
if ($userProfile[$upAttribute].toString() -ne 14 )
 {
  if ($userProfile.AccountName -like "i:0#.f|ldapmember|colbs")
  {
         $newvalue = $userProfile[$upAttribute].toString()
         $newvalue = $newvalue.Replace($currentURLValue, $newURLValue)
         $userProfile[$upAttribute].Value = $newvalue
         $userProfile.Commit()
  }
 }
}
```

You can remove the AccountName -like condition if you want every account updated. Also, if you want to update other properties besides PersonalSiteCapabilities, here is a link describing each

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj679700(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj679700%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually hunt down how to do these things in PowerShell, is to find the page where it is done in UI (usually a page in _LAYOUTS), find out what assembly that contains the codebehind and what methods are involved (lookin PAGE directive), load the assembly into Reflector and see how SharePoint does it.